# Setting attributes on object instances in Python via map builtin

Tags: python, dictionary

There's got to be a way to do this with `map()`

This:

```
for inst in list_of_instances:
    inst.run()
```

Can be done like this:

```
map(operator.methodcaller('run'), list_of_instances)
```

How can this be done with `map()`?

```
for inst in list_of_instances:
    inst.some_setting = True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
map(lambda inst: setattr(inst, 'some_setting', True), list_of_instances)
```

or using list comprehension:

```
[setattr(inst, 'some_setting', True) for inst in list_of_instances]
```

BTW, I think simple `for` loop is better than `map` because

- `for` loop is easier to read.
- `map`, list comprehension versions generate temporary list (`[None, None, None, ..., None]`)

Comment: Thanks! I was so close to figuring this out but I am really tired.

Comment: I agree with your points as well, I just figured it had to be doable and I found it odd that there is operator.methodcaller and operator.itemgetter but no operator.itemsetter.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it's not a good idea.

`map` is designed to work only with pure (immutable) operations, i.e. functions that return a *new* object. The lack of an `itemsetter` function reflects this idea. Since your code modifies objects *in place*, you should use a `for` loop instead.

This is important because in Python 3, `map` [doesn't return a list](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). It returns an iterator object, which calls your function on demand. So under Python 3, your code won't run at all.

The `map` vs `for` distinction isn't unique to Python. In JavaScript, you have `map` and `forEach`; in Haskell, you have `map` and `traverse`. It's important to distinguish between these two fundamentally different things.